# Контейер не сжимается до высоты контента

Tags: html, css, flexbox

На моей странице есть ряд из 4-х контейнеров, которые должны сжиматься до высоты того контейнера, имеющего наибольшую высоту (то есть они должны быть одинакового размера и при этом контент не должен выходить за их границу). Сейчас они принимают одинаковую высоту, но я не понимаю от чего она зависит.

```css
section {
    background-color: #293C40;
}
h1 {
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
    text-align: center;
}
.recipies {
    padding: 3px 3% 3px 3%;
}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #D1D5DE;
}
h3 {
    text-align: left;
    color: #D1D5DE;
}
h4 {
    color: #293C40;
}
.type {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    gap: 1%;
}
.card {
    padding: 1%;
    background-color: #D68341;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1 1 0;
    flex-basis: 100%;
}
.first {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    flex: 1 1 0;
}
.card img {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 30%;
}
.card a {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #293C40;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #f2f4f3;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    bottom: 2px;
}
html, head, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
a, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<section class="recipies">
        <h2 id="best">Лучшие рецепты</h2>
        <div class="cards">
            <h3>Русская кухня</h3>
            <div class="type">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="first">
                        <img src="https://salon3d.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Gem-6-020-1024x655.jpg" alt="borscht"><h4>Борщ</h4><p>Горячий заправочный суп на основе свёклы, которая придаёт ему характерный красный цвет.</p>
                    </div>
                    <a href="pages/borscht.html" class="button">Подробнее</a>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="first">
                        <img src="https://salon3d.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Gem-6-020-1024x655.jpg" alt="vinegret"><h4>Винегрет</h4><p>Холодное блюдо русской кухни, закуска, разновидность салата, обязательным ингредиентом которого в современной кулинарии является отварная или печёная свёкла.</p>
                    </div>
                    <a href="pages/vinegret.html" class="button">Подробнее</a>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="first">
                        <img src="https://salon3d.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Gem-6-020-1024x655.jpg" alt="pelmeni"><h4>Пельмени</h4><p>Термически обработанные изделия из пресного теста с начинкой из рубленого мяса или рыбы.</p>
                    </div>
                    <a href="pages/pelmeni.html" class="button">Подробнее</a>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="first">
                        <img src="https://salon3d.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Gem-6-020-1024x655.jpg" alt="Blini"><h4>Блины</h4><p>Блюдо русской кухни, выпекаемое из жидкого теста на сковороде.</p>
                    </div>
                    <a href="pages/blini.html" class="button">Подробнее</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <h3>Итальянская кухня</h3>
            <div class="type">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="first">
                        <img src="https://salon3d.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Gem-6-020-1024x655.jpg" alt="pizza margarita"><h4>Пицца Маргарита</h4><p>Типичная неаполитанская пицца, приготовленная с помидорами Сан-Марцано, сыром моцарелла, свежим базиликом, солью и оливковым маслом первого отжима.</p>
                    </div>
                    <a href="pages/margarita.html" class="button">Подробнее</a>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="first">
                        <img src="https://salon3d.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Gem-6-020-1024x655.jpg" alt="lasagna"><h4>Лазанья</h4><p>Блюдо итальянской кухни, традиционно приготовляемое из тонких листов теста (собственно и называющихся лазанья) со слоями различной начинки.</p>
                    </div>
                    <a href="pages/lasagna.html" class="button">Подробнее</a>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="first">
                        <img src="https://salon3d.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Gem-6-020-1024x655.jpg" alt="pasta carbonara"><h4>Карбонара</h4><p>Итальянское блюдо из пасты из Рима, приготовленное из яиц, твердого сыра, вяленой свинины и черного перца.</p>
                    </div>
                    <a href="pages/carbonara.html" class="button">Подробнее</a>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="first">
                        <img src="https://salon3d.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Gem-6-020-1024x655.jpg" alt="risotto"><h4>Ризотто</h4><p>Блюдо итальянской кухни из риса, с мягким, сливочным вкусом.</p>
                    </div>
                    <a href="pages/risotto.html" class="button">Подробнее</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: почитайте про CSS свойство flex

Comment: Отличное решение моей проблемы. Поясните, пожалуйста, свой ответ

Comment: вы прочитали про свойство?

Comment: да, прочитал, и не один раз

Answer (score 0):

нужно использовать для img фиксированную высоту, которую я задавал в vh